# Get fbclid parameter or fbc cookie from mobile traffic

Tags: facebook, cookies, parameters

We are running Facebook ads and need the fbclid in the URL parameters of the landing page. Desktop traffic is fine but mobile traffic does not have the fbclid in the URL or the fbc cookie.

I am aware that the cookie [fbc is the fbclid](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/parameters/fbp-and-fbc/). I used a simple [script](https://github.com/elbomnetanel/fbclid/blob/master/fbclid_catcher.js) to get that value and add it as a parameter, but that cookie doesn't seem to be present at document.cookie in mobile traffic either.

Is there another place this could be? Is there a Facebook ad setting I need to change to ensure we can access the fbclid?

Any help on this would be amazing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The documentation you linked to, says that these links “sometimes” contain an fbclid parameter, and that in those cases, the pixel takes over the job of populating the cookies. But if that parameter isn’t there in the first place, the pixel has nothing to set. I don’t know under what conditions you can expect the parameter to be present, resp. what Facebook’s criteria for including it are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked at FB and now am a consultant doing these types of integrations.

FBC is currently not being passed through Facebook's in-app browser. It is still accessible in Chrome (on Android). So if you're opening Facebook in Chrome and clicking a link FBC should be present.

Comment: For Facebook's in-app browser, How to get fbc or fbclid? We need that for offline conversion tracking